# Listview _ItemClick event not firing (XL2007)

Tags: excel, vba, listview, events

I have a userform containing a standard MSComctlLib v6 (SP6) ListView control, called `lvwTables`.  By the time the user gets to see it, there are about twenty or so ListItems added to the control.  I'm trying to trap the `_ItemClick` event using what I think* is the correct form, i.e.

```
Private Sub lvwTables_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)

    'blah

End Sub
```

But the event sub is never triggered.  Other click events (e.g. `_Click` and `_ColumnClick`) are working fine.

Has anyone successfully trapped this event in XL07, and if so how did you do it?

( * I'm referring to the web for info as I don't have access to the control's online help or any other documentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of further testing it seems the listview's `_ItemClick` event fires when clicking somewhere in the FIRST COLUMN ONLY, unless its `.FullRowSelect` property is set to True.

I didn't spot this before as the width of my first column is zero and I had `.FullRowSelect` turned off.

Hopefully this will help someone in my position in the future!